Report IEC Prefixed Sizes from Commands Like ls
In a GNOME terminal with a bash shell, is there a convenient way to have commands like ls and du output human readable sizes using IEC prefixes. Looking at the man page for ls, it looks like they are actually already IEC sizes when using ls -lh, but the "old style" prefixes are used (K, M, and G instead of Ki, Mi, and Gi).

Usually (and for GNU ls in particular) K, M, G... are short for KiB, MiB, GiB (kibibyte, mebibyte, gibibyte) already, not KB, MB, GB (kilobyte, megabyte, gigabyte). I've never seen Ki/Mi/Gi used on their own without a unit (like B for byte here).

Note that bash is a shell, an interpreter for a language specialised in running commands, it's not a terminal. If run with in a terminal or terminal emulator such as xterm, tmux, gnome-terminal it will be interactive and let you edit command lines with its readline editor. But bash itself doesn't do anything with file size units. It's separate  commands such as du or ls (the GNU implementations thereof at least, -h is not a standard option to those) that do.

Adoption of the new prefixes is low. I would honestly be surprised if such a thing ever left the documentation.

Related: Converting a variable to human-readable format.

@StéphaneChazelas I confirmed that they were indeed short for the IEC sizes in the ls man page. I was just wondering if I could print them that way to resolve the ambiguity (so I don't forget and have to look for it again).
